# Como criar esse efeito/animação

Tags: html, css

[image: circuit board like]

Desejo usar esse efeito de placa de circuitos como animação (começando pelos lados e se desenhando até se encontrarem no centro) no meu site. Mas eu não consigo de maneira nenhuma.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso usando somente CSS? Sem utilizar SVG ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Shadow, é possível fazer com HTML, CSS E JS, só com HTML e CSS, creio que será impossível.

Comment: Pode fazer isso fácil com jquery. É bom ter a imagens já prontas em gif ou png se precisar de transparência. Mas se pretende que o desenho seja feito em runtime é mais complexo e amplo demais.

Comment: Acredito que o beneficio de fazer fazer somente com HTML e CSS, inviabiliza o tempo para fazer isso, sendo inviável. Segue o que o @DanielOmine disse :)

Comment: @DanielOmine Entendi, cara. Vou tentar fazer assim então, valeu :))

Comment: @FabianoLothor Entendo, vou tentar fazer como o Daniel disse, então.

Comment: @David Vou seguir mesmo. Mais tarde eu do um retorno com o resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou mostrar um caminho para chegar nesse resultado:

```css
.container {
 margin-top: 75px;
 position: relative;
}
.line-a {
  border-top: solid 1px;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}

.line-b {
  border-top: solid 1px;
   width: 30px;
   min-height: 75px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 276px;
   top: -34px;
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-64deg);
}

.line-c {
   border-top: solid 1px;
   width: 100px;
   top: -26px;
   left: 263px;
   min-height: 2px;
   position: absolute;
}

.ball {
   border: solid 1px;
   width: 7px;
   height: 7px;
   top: -29px;
   left: 362px;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <span class="line-a"></span>
  <span class="line-b"></span>
  <span class="line-c"></span>
  <span class="ball"></span>
</section>
```

Comment: No começo estava fazendo assim mesmo! 
Mas estava achando muito mão. Por enquanto vou deixar dessa maneira.
Obrigado pelo toque Samuel!